# ValueError: Invalid dataset identifier (invalid dataset identifier)

Tags: python, pytorch, hdf5, h5py

I was trying to load the dataset `.hdf5` format using the below code of shape `(1000,)` but i was having the error `ValueError: Invalid location identifier (invalid location identifier)`. The error is popping up when i try to load the dataset into the pytorch dataloader.

```py
with h5py.File(dataset_path, 'r') as f:
    data = f['default']
    print(data.shape)

Ouput:
(1000,)
```

```py
# Define the dataset
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset_path):
        super().__init__()
        with h5py.File(dataset_path, 'r') as f:
            self.data = f['default']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]

# Load the dataset
dataset_path = 'dataset.hdf5'

train_dataset = MyDataset(dataset_path)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-c3c741b81eff> in <module>
     22 
     23 train_dataset = MyDataset(dataset_path)
---> 24 train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True)

6 frames
h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in shape(self)
    472 
    473         with phil:
--> 474             shape = self.id.shape
    475 
    476         # If the file is read-only, cache the shape to speed-up future uses.

h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.shape.__get__()

h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.shape.__get__()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.get_space()

ValueError: Invalid dataset identifier (invalid dataset identifier)
```

and i am receiving the same error when i am doing this `f.get("default")`

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am experiencing the same issue, sigh.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that reading the HDF file with `with` causes it to be closed immediately at the constructor return. The `h5py` module is designed with the idea of the file being kept open, so that data can be read (or written) as needed with a lazy approach rather than upfront.